# Returning array in Javascript function after splitting string

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

Very new to Javascript and not understanding why my tutorial isn't accepting my code as an answer...

Challenge is to create a function that returns an array after breaking up string into separate words.

Here's what I have so far:

```
function cutName(namestr) {
  var newArray = namestr.split(' ');
  return newArray();
}
```

This seems to work when called, for example returning the following when given this string "hello does this work" as an argument:

```
[ 'hello', 'does', 'this', 'work' ]
```

What the heck am I doing wrong here? Shouldn't the above code suffice for an answer?

Comment: Why are you appending `()` to your array variable, its not a function

Comment: Why return newArray() instead of return newArray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the parenthesis from `return newArray;`. When learning JavaScript, you might want to look into tools like [JSBin](http://www.jsbin.com), they give you a lot of helpful feedback and realtime results.

**JavaScript**

```
function cutName(namestr) {
  var newArray = namestr.split(' ');
  return newArray;
}

var arr = cutName('hello does this work');
console.log(Array.isArray(arr));
console.log(arr);
```

**console output**

```
true
["hello", "does", "this", "work"]
```

[See the JSBin](http://jsbin.com/vasawudaju/3/edit)

Answer (score 2):

you should return without parenthesis like so...

```
return newArray;
```

Comment: hi, if you found my answer is correct please mark it as.

Comment: You should think about explaining why your answer is correct rather than just providing a "do this" answer. :)

Comment: yes you are right... this one was just a small typo :)

Answer (score 2):

Quite likely it is unhappy with `return newArray();`  newArray is an array, not a function.